# iOS Core Data minimal memory footprint

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm using Core Data for data storage. The data contains just 3 records, and columns contain just short strings. But 'Instruments' shows 4.02 MiB allocated by "VM: Core Data Object IDs".

[image]

It can be reproduced even in new Master-Detail project created by xcode wizard. After a single row is added, Core Data allocates those 4 MB.

It seems like some minimal memory chunk that is always allocated. Can it be reduced? I want to use it in Today widget, so memory usage is important.

Comment: It sounds about right, all objects have overhead and for performance chunks of memory are often allocated pre-empting future allocation. Memory allocation is CPU intensive so its cheaper to allocate a chunk. I shouldn't think 4MB is going to hinder performance. If you're that concerned about memory usage, perhaps a rethink of your app's structure could help? Ask yourself why you need Core Data to store 3 short strings.

Comment: @LeonStorey Because I thought Core Data is supposed to be a common way to store data. And it should scale to any data size. Maybe later there are will be more records. Even if I need to store just several records, I don't think implementing own serialization, querying, updating logic is a good way to go.

Comment: When usage is tight use a storage medium based around your current requirements, then adjust in the future if requirements change. Core Data is pushed by Apple to be a common way to store relational data, although for your needs a relational database seems overkill. I would look into using `NSUserDefaults`, which using App Group's can have a shared persistent store between your widget and app or benchmark `SQLite` to see if it performs better for your needs than Core Data. Other than that, it would be serializing the data into a file.